# Exchange Online - Unable to change end time of event in progress

Tags: office365, exchange-server

Assume the following:

1. In Office365 a room resource has been created with the default
   settings.
2. A  meeting is booked at this room.
3. The meeting has started.

The organizer then *changes the end-time* of the meeting (either to extend it or end it early).

The room auto-replies with 
`Your meeting request was declined. The invitation was declined because it occurred in the past.`

Interestingly, at this point, the event then completely disappears from the room's calendar - as if it never existed.

This is a reasonable use-case. Which settings would allow the organizer to achieve the above scenario without being declined?